# Updating MongoDB with a nested object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, nested, javascript-objects

So I have been trying to show a unit of measure on each item I create. I have no problems displaying the item and the unit but when I try to update it, It just changes my object into a string. I believe my problem lays in my changeHandler because its not letting me update the specific values, rather just letting me change the whole thing. Do i need to nest my values deeper? Or use a different call to change the values of toteBags?

I have tried changing the model and returning different JSON types like objects or arrays and the only way I can seem to display it correctly is if i use an object. I have also tried changing the e.target name value but when I do that I cannot type anything in the input box.

```
    const changeHandler = (e) => {
    setItem({ ...item, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
}


const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.put(`http://localhost:8000/api/product/${id}/edit`, item, { withCredentials: true })
        .then((res) => {
            navigate('/dashboard')
            console.log("FOUND IT", res.data)
            console.log("ToteBags::::", res.data.toteBags)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
            console.log('^^^^^^^', err.response.data);
            // if (err.response.data.error) {
            //     setErrors(err.response.data.error.errors)
            //     console.log('^^Errors^^', errors)
            // }
        })
}


return (
    <div className='count p-4'>
        <img className='logo2' src={logo} alt='logo' />
        <form className='m-3 form-location' onSubmit={submitHandler} >
            <div className='main-card'>
                <div className='p-2 item-card'>
                    <label className='form-label col'>24x24x32 Tote Bags: </label>
                    <input className='form-control form-styling' type="number" onChange={changeHandler} value={item.toteBags.quantity} name='toteBags.quantity' />
                    <label className='form-label col'>Unit of Measure: </label>
                    <input className='form-control form-styling' type="string" onChange={changeHandler} value={item.toteBags.uoM} name='toteBags.uoM' />
                </div>
            <button className='btn m-2'>Count</button>
            </div>


        </form>
    </div>

)}
```

This is the model Im using

```
const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
toteBags:{
    quantity: Number,
    uoM: String,
}
```

Lastly my controller

```
    updateItem:(req,res) => {
    Item.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, req.body, {new:true, runValidators: true})
    .then(updatedItem => {
        res.json(updatedItem)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json({message: 'Something went wrong updating', error: err})
    })
},
```